# The dimension of special vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

For integer $k$, define a function $f_k\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to take any value on $(k,k+1)$ and $0$ on $\Bbb R\setminus(k,k+1).$ let $\mathcal F=\{f_k\colon k\in\mathbb Z\}$ be a family of these functions. Note that the functions in $\mathcal F$ are linearly independent. Now, define $$V:=\left\lbrace \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z} c_{k} f_{k} \colon f_k\in\mathcal F \ \&\ c_k\in\Bbb R \right\rbrace.$$ Then, $V$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$? Is that right? If so, What is the dimension of $V$?

Comment: Yes, yes and infinite.

Comment: @zkutch, Thank you very much. How can I show the dimension is infinite

Comment: By definition: for each $n$ natural, system $\{f_1,\cdots ,f_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @zkutch, Is it because countable of finite union is countable. Also, when we say infinite do we have an specific cardinal number

Comment: Notice that each of the functions $f_k \in \mathrm{V}$ and the system $(f_k)$ is independent.

Comment: @WillM., I was confused since I each function in $\mathcal F$ are linealy independent but the usually the span is finite of linear combination.

Comment: @WillM. If there is different to write $V$ in such way that they will be equivalent

Comment: @00GB I am not sure exactly what is confusing: $\mathrm{V}$ has finite dimension if there exists a finite system $(v_i)_{1 \leq i \leq d}$ such that _every vector_ in $\mathrm{V}$ is linear combination of the $(v_i).$ Regardless of how many $f_k$ you take, if $f_N$ is the last of them, $f_{N + 1}$ is already not in the span, so it _immediately and trivially_ violates the definition of finite dimension.

Comment: @WillM. Thank you for getting back to me. you used the word system . did you mean linear independent.

Comment: @zkutch, I do have one more question about $V$. I know each $f_k$ in $\mathcal F$ is linearly independent but the why elements in $V$ are linearly independent. Could you please explain this to me.

Comment: Why you think so? For example, let's take $f_1 \in V$, then $c f_1 \in V$ for some $c$, but $f_1$ and $cf_1$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: @zkutch, sorry but I got confused. Maybe I missed something. But why $V$ is a vector space though . I thought this would be spans and linearly independent

Comment: Vectors space contain not only linearly independent elements. What have confused you?

Comment: @zkutch, Okay, let $B=\{A\subset\mathbb Z\colon A \text{is infinite}\}$ and $D=\{\sum_{k\in A} f_k \colon A\in B\}$. Is $D$ lineally independent ? Could you please help with this. If it is right or not?